# Why there's no possible conversion (generic type restricted with interface)?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I've got following classes.

```
interface ICommand {. . .} 

class ShutdownCommand : ICommand { . . .}

class Message<T> where T : ICommand { . . .}

class Communicator
{
    void Send(Message<ICommand> a_msg) { . . .}
}
```

When I call following code, I get an error that there's no possible conversion from the type `Message<ShutdownCommand>` to the `Message<ICommand>`. It's not intuitive for me since `ShutdownCommand` inherits from `ICommand`.

```
var message = new Message<ShutdownCommand>();
m_communicator.SendCommand(message);
```

I know I can solve such problem with adding non-generic interface for a Message class and use it as parameter type in Send() method.
Regardless it could be fixed in the way I described above... I'm curious why there's no possible conversion if from the code above arises conversion should be possible.

Comment: Learn about covariance.

Comment: One simple fix is to make your Send method generic: `void Send<T>(Message<T> a_msg) where T:ICommand { . . .}`

Comment: Notice that `ShutdownCommand` does not *inherit* from `ICommand`, it *implements* it

Comment: This is a good interview question, to instantly check presence of mind..he he he